# Convert from Object to Original Class

Tags: java, class, object, types

I'm storing a instance of `Entry` class in an `Object`.

```
Entry newentry = new Entry(j, 0.0);
Object test = newentry;
```

How can I convert the `test` Object back into an `Entry` class to access the `Entry` class method `getValue()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typecast it:

```
Entry newentry = new Entry(j, 0.0);
Entry test = (Entry) newentry;
```

Also, if `getValue` is a **class method**, you don't need an **instance** to access it, you can call it directly:

```
Object x = Entry.getValue();
```

Comment: it is also recommended to check for instance type before typecasting.

Answer (score 0):

First answer:

*Change the datatype of test from Object to Entry in your example.*

Second answer:

*If you really need to assign it to an object (in this case, a variable called "test") somewhere along the way (for some reason) then you can do this to get it back:*

```
Object val = ((Entry)test).getValue();
```